# How to create such view in Titanium Alloy Android App?

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules, titanium-android

I am a newbie, and learning Titanium Alloy to make Android App.

I have created an HTML design of a List row, which I want to make in Native Titanium. (The list will have multiple rows)

I saw an example from Titanium Docs, and wrote this but it is giving simple list style.

```
<Alloy>
    <ListView id="list">
        <ListSection>
            <ListItem title="List item 1"></ListItem>
            <ListItem title="List item 2"></ListItem>
            <ListItem title="List item 3"></ListItem>
        </ListSection>
    </ListView>
</Alloy>
```

Please suggest the way to go forward with the design of my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Use ItemTemplates to make any UI you want, which you can then populate through properties in the ListItems.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/ListViews-section-37521650_ListViews-ItemTemplate

Comment: If you don't mind can you please provide an example to make my desired UI. The doc of appcelerator is not good. It should have screenshot that this would become by writing this code etc. Thanks.

Comment: If you scroll down http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ListView you'll find several Alloy examples.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but is it because  doesn't have a capital A?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in writing here @ stackoverflow. Edited the code. It is not the problem BTW.